# Razer Blade 15 on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS only right speaker works

Tags: drivers, sound, speakers

On a new installed laptop with Ubuntu 20.04 only the right speaker of the laptop works.

How can I fix the issue?

Comment: Hello. What have you tried to troubleshoot this? Also what does this statement from your question mean?  if this is for example info, what someone wants.

Comment: There is a question: I am looking for a solution to fix the issue.